# I want to achieve a controlled glass with transparency transparent background

Tags: transparency

[image]

i want to achieve this simple glass morphism effect with no dramatic lighting artifacts, with blurry effect

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Super simple actually!

Just a Principled BSDF with `Transmission` at `1` and `Roughness` at `0.2`.

[image]

**Higher Roughness = More Blur**

Comment: hi blenderMaster15 sorry i did not get email, or notification that you answered i am seeing this now after 22 hours. thanks for the answer , i want to get transparent so if i overlay in photoshop or any other image software behind image will be blur do you know how to do that thanks.

Comment: Well, for starters, what I did is I made 2 thin cubes. One had a magic texture, another had the Principled BSDF I made for this answer. As you can see, the magic texture cube is blurred out behind the Glass cube. If you want to add an image on top of the glass texture, that is possible, and I can show you how if you'd like.

Comment: @user157008 It is impossible to make a transparent PNG without a background image but keep the blur factor to work in other software. In real life, the blurriness is a property of a physical object - you don't create real physical objects in Blender, so every property they have is faked. You can transfer transparency with things like alpha transparency from one software to the other, but the blurriness is calculated in regard to what the image behind looks like and how a blurred version looks like.

Comment: @user157008 Since a PNG only holds color and transparency information, it would have to trigger a blur operation fitting the image editing software in which it gets opened to do this. And even then - Photoshop itself doesn't blur background images to some overlaying image, but the background image itself. In Photoshop you could convert a background image into a smart object, add a blur filter and use a mask to apply it only where the PNG with transparency is overlaying it, but that's not really the same and the blur would still have to be generated in Photoshop, not Blender.